# "not as ... as I crave" or "not as ... as what I crave?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, syntactic-analysis, verb-agreement

In the sentence *I wanted to build my knowledge through a variety of opportunities, but at my current school these opportunities aren’t as vast as what I crave*

I want to convey a meaning like "not as vast as the opportunities I crave". My theory is that the *what* is necessary to convey such meaning, and that *not as vast as I crave* sounds weird and unnatural

Which one is correct, "not as vast as I crave" or "not as vast as what I crave"?

Comment: Even better would be "these opportunities aren't as vast as _those_ I crave". Your intuition is correct. I also agree that it sounds awkward as just "as I crave".

Comment: I agree with Aleksandr. You could also put 'those which I crave'.

Comment: I prefer the version without *what*. The version with *what* sounds less BrE or even AmE, and more InE.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used the word 'opportunities' which may be numbered or counted, it seems safer to use the adjective 'numerous', rather than 'vast', hence, the answer could be....'aren't as numerous as I desire'

'I wanted to build my knowledge through a variety of opportunities, but at my current school these opportunities aren’t as numerous as I desire.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to build my knowledge through a variety of opportunities, but at my current school these opportunities aren’t ***as vast as*** (what) I crave.

This is a comparative construction, containing a ***Comparative Phrase*** - *as vast as (what) I crave*. It is a *Scalar comparison*, It falls under *Equality*.

This is a ***Term Comparison*** and not a ***Set Comparison***.

So what happens in ***Term Comparison***?

The first term is being compared to the second term.

> ... these opportunities aren't as vast as my expectation.

The first term - *These opportunities*.

The second term can be a clause, a phrase or any other grammatical construction. Here in this example sentence it is a Noun Phrase (NP) - *my expectation*.

In the construction - *as vast as my expectation* - the first *as* is an adverb. We call it a ***Comparative Governor***, and the second *as* is a preposition. The ***Expanded comparative Complement*** is *as my expectation*.

In your sentence -

> 1. these opportunities aren't as vast as I crave.
> 2. these opportunities aren't as vast as what I crave.

Both #1 and #2 are correct, grammatically. Whether to add *what* or drop it solely depends on the writer/speaker.

Sentence #1 and #2 doesn't have the same grammatical structure.

In sentence #1, the complement of the preposition *as* is a clause, we call it ***Comparative Clause*** - *I crave _*. In your second sentence the complement of the preposition *as* is a fused-relative construction - *what I crave*.

So to direct answer your question, yes you can optionally use *what* in your original sentence.

[Terminologies and explanations are based on The Cambridge Grammar of English Language. Last portion of the answer and the whole analysis is mine.]

Answer (score 0):

To me the word crave does sound good or appropriate. To answer the question as stated, Of the two "not as vast as I crave" would be my choice.

But i would use something like

> I wanted to build my knowledge through a variety of opportunities, but at my current school these opportunities were not as numerous as i desire.

or better yet.

> I wanted to build my knowledge through a variety of opportunities, but at my current school i found that the opportunities available were insufficient for my needs.